# proving that the A and B are conditionally independent given C

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, probability

I was given the following joint distribution table defining a tri-variate distribution over binary random variables:

```
   a  b  c      p
0  0  0  0  0.192
1  0  0  1  0.144
2  0  1  0  0.048
3  0  1  1  0.216
4  1  0  0  0.192
5  1  0  1  0.064
6  1  1  0  0.048
7  1  1  1  0.096
```

and I was to prove that A and B are conditionally independent given C.
I ended up loading the distribution into a pandas dataframe and with this cumbersome proof:

```
c0 = p[p.c == 0]
c0.p /= c0.p.sum()
c0
   a  b  c    p
0  0  0  0  0.4
2  0  1  0  0.1
4  1  0  0  0.4
6  1  1  0  0.1
np.outer(c0.groupby('a').p.sum(), c0.groupby('b').p.sum())
array([[0.4, 0.1],
       [0.4, 0.1]])
```

and then the same for `p[p.c == 1]`.

Am I missing something much simpler following some probability theory result? If not, am I missing a much nicer way to write the pandas/numpy code?
let me know if this should migrate to cross-validated, or out of SO :)

Answer (score 3):

It might help to use a helper function to encapsulate a repeated part of the calculation:

```
def partial(df, givens, index='c'):
    result = df.groupby(givens, as_index=False)['p'].sum().set_index(index)
    return result
```

Then you can express all the partial distributions more easily:

```
FAB = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'b': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'p': [0.192, 0.144, 0.048, 0.216, 0.192, 0.064, 0.048, 0.096]})
FC = partial(FAB, ['c'])
FA = partial(FAB, ['c','a'])
FB = partial(FAB, ['c','b'])
FAB = FAB.set_index('c')
```

And the product of `FA` and `FB` can be found like this:

```
FA_FB = (pd.merge(FA, FB, on=['c'], suffixes=['a', 'b']))
FA_FB['p'] = (FA_FB['pa'] * FA_FB['pb']) / FC['p']
FA_FB = FA_FB.drop(['pa', 'pb'], axis=1)
```

(Aside: Notice that `FAB`, `FA`, `FB` and `FC` are all indexed by `c` values. This allows us to perform arithmetical operations on these DataFrames like

```
(FA_FB['pa'] * FA_FB['pb']) / FC['p']
```

even though `FC` has a different shape than `FA_FB`. Pandas automatically aligns the rows properly for us based on matching indices. That's the reason why `set_index(index)` was used in the `partial` helper function.)

Now to test that `FA_FB` equals `FAB`:

```
diff = [dfi.set_index(['a','b'], append=True) for dfi in (FA_FB, FAB)]
diff = diff[0] - diff[1]
assert (np.allclose(diff, 0))
```

---

Here is the code above in one runnable chunk:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def partial(df, givens, index='c'):
    result = df.groupby(givens, as_index=False)['p'].sum().set_index(index)
    return result

FAB = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'b': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'p': [0.192, 0.144, 0.048, 0.216, 0.192, 0.064, 0.048, 0.096]})
FC = partial(FAB, ['c'])
FA = partial(FAB, ['c','a'])
FB = partial(FAB, ['c','b'])
FAB = FAB.set_index('c')

# print(FAB)
FA_FB = (pd.merge(FA, FB, on=['c'], suffixes=['a', 'b']))
FA_FB['p'] = (FA_FB['pa'] * FA_FB['pb']) / FC['p']
FA_FB = FA_FB.drop(['pa', 'pb'], axis=1)
# print(FA_FB)
# print(FAB)
diff = [dfi.set_index(['a','b'], append=True) for dfi in (FA_FB, FAB)]
diff = diff[0] - diff[1]
assert (np.allclose(diff, 0))
```

---

In retrospect: One issue you were facing with your code was having to address the case `c == 0` and then repeat the calculation for `c == 1`. Of course, you could use a `for-loop` to handle this.
But since you are using Pandas, it is often possible (and faster) to avoid breaking up the data into pieces and instead trying to express the calculation in terms of operations that affect the entire DataFrame as a whole.

Thus, above, no effort was made to separate the cases `c == 0` from `c == 1`. Instead, the `c` values were shoved into the `index` and Pandas' automatic alignment of indices was use to take care of joining or arithmetically combining rows appropriately for us.

Another advantage to using Pandas this way (instead of using a `for-loop`) is that the code can handle an arbitrary number of different `c` values with no change to the code.

Comment: thanks for the effort! but I'm not sure that this one's less cumbersome than mine... I'll wait till someone offers some cool `pivot` based solution, and if not I'll accept yours. sorry for the subjectivity